# Resource directory for tests in a Play application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I need some resources (text files) for my tests in a Scala Play 2.0 application. Where can I put these files?

In a maven app I would put them into `src/test/resources`, but I cannot find anything about an equal directory in the Play documentation.

I can put them in the `conf`directory, but I only need them when I test the application.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Call

```
play "show test:resource-directory"
```

in the console and it shows you the absolute path to your resource directory in test mode.
It will be in "test/resources".

"show" is a sbt command (or task) that enables you to retrieve the values of settings.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I didn't know about the show-command before.

Comment: The same works for **activator** projects. Just run `activator "show test:resource-directory"` instead.

Comment: And of course with plain **sbt**: `sbt "show test:resource-directory"`

Comment: Excellent response! Thank you for taking the time to answer the meta question of how to get the information as well.

Comment: In new SBT it's `sbt "show test:resourceDirectory"`

Answer (score 3):

Elevating SathOkh's comment for more visibility.

With sbt 1.3.13:

```
$ sbt "show test:resourceDirectory"
...
[info] /path/to/project/test/resources
```

Answer (score 0):

or nowadays, less deprecated:

```
$ sbt "show Test/resourceDirectory"
...
[info] /path/to/project/test/resources
```

Comment: Which versions of sbt support this?